# Is there a $f(x)$ such that $f'(x)=g(x)$, $g'(x)=h(x)$, $h'(x)=f(x)$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Hopefully, the question in the title is clear enough - I am aware there are functions which obey $f'(x)=g(x)$, $g'(x)=f(x)$ but are there any that obeys the relationship shown in the title?

Comment: So $f'''(x)=f(x)$? A nice linear differential equation!

Comment: You are trying to solve the ODE $y'''=y$. There is a standard method of finding all solutions.

Comment: Thank you for all the help! I'm quite new to this but why was my question downvoted? Was there something inappropiate about what I asked?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clearly we have the trivial solution.

Then from the first and second equations we have $f''(x)=g'(x)=h(x)$ and combining with the third we get $f'''(x)=f(x),$ which is a third order linear ordinary differential equation.

Looking for a solution of the form $e^{\lambda x}$ we obtain the auxiliary equation $$\lambda^{3}-1=(\lambda -1)(\lambda ^2+\lambda+1)=(\lambda -1)((\lambda+\frac{1}{2})^2+\frac{3}{4})=0.$$

So we have the roots $\lambda=1$ and $\lambda=-\frac{1}{2}\pm i\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$ and thus the general solution is $$f(x)=Ae^{x}+Be^{-\frac{x}{2}}\cos(x\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2})+Ce^{-\frac{x}{2}}\sin(x\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}).$$

Answer (score 0):

This should be a comment rather than an answer, but the answer to your question is yes. This is an example of a linear system of first order ordinary differential equations. There is a theorem that ensures that solutions to these exist and are unique. You can your system of equations as
\begin{equation} 
\frac{d F}{dt}= M F
\end{equation}
And can be solved by diagonalizing M.